# What is the best practice for creating a route that can be accessed by 2 roles NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Regarding best practice in creating routes in Node.Js Express.Js. For example, if I have 4 roles, namely headmaster, student and teacher, then I have a route called `/sliders`, which in the application these sliders can be seen by both teacher, student, and administrator only.

When creating routes and middleware for checking roles, what are the best practices?

I.
Should I create 1 endpoints and 1 middleware that can be access by student and teacher only?

For example:

```
v1.get('/sliders', isUserOrTeacher, controller.findAll)
```

and my middleware code:

```
const isUserOrTeacher = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.payload.aud).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err })
      return
    }

    Role.find(
      {
        _id: { $in: user.roles }
      },
      (err, roles) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err })
          return
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          if (roles[i].name === 'student' || roles[i].name === 'teacher' || roles[i].name === 'admin') {
            next()
            return
          }
        }

        logger.error(req.method, req.originalUrl, '. Error isUserOrTeacher: ' + req.payload)
        return sendUnauthorized(res)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

II.
or i should make 2 different endpoint and 2 middleware

for example:

```
v1.get('/user/sliders', isUser, controller.findAll)
v1.get('/teacher/sliders', isTeacher, controller.findAll)
```

III.
or can i make route like this?? And how the coding? for middleware:

```
v1.get('/sliders', isUser, isTeacher, isAdmin, controller.findAll)
```

Which one is the best practice?

Comment: 1st solution is the best one for me, you are in a specific case so a specific middleware isn't a bad thing

Comment: what if i have add the another rule someday? I should add ```roles[i].name === 'staff'``` in ```if``` condition inside isUserOrTeacher function? @ValentinMarguerie

Comment: You will need to modify your middleware to match this new case but that is for me the only real solution. For instance, your last solution cannot work simply because, if  someone is an Admin, he will not pass `isUser` and `isTeacher` middleware and the second on is a bit weird because you are reaching the same function with 2 routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three concerns that you should separate and not mix up:

- which resource is accessed (the route)
- which user is accessing the resource (authentication)
- which role does the user need to access the resource (authorisation)

Consequently, you'd use different middlewares for this:

```
v1.get('/sliders', isAuthenticated, hasRole(['teacher', 'admin']), controller.findAll)
```

The `isAuthenticated` middleware would load the user object from the database or session store and store it on the request object (or throw if the client is not logged in). The middleware created by `hasRole` would then check whether the user object has one of the given roles, or throw a "missing permission" error. The controller would finally load and return the resource.
You can also make the role check part of the data provider (e.g. a database service) that the controller uses, so that it is done consistently for all accesses, no matter from where.

Comment: +1 for `hasRole` middleware. Though I recommend using `app.use(isAuthenticated)` above all routes that require authentication, to avoid inadvertantly adding a route that misses authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I will do a middleware named `canGet<Controller name>` and the code in it will be

```js
 switch(userRole): 
  case 'teacher':
    next();
    break;
  case 'user':
    next();
    break;
  default:
   res.statut(403);
```

And then you can add any role in it, and without changing the name of the function in your route

Answer (score 0):

I am agreeable with option No.1. I have one project which has to handle 7 roles. It has been running for 2 months now. I declare the roles as below:

```
  const express = require("express");
  const router = express.Router();
  const role = require("../authentication/authRole");
  const auth = require("../authentication/authentication");

  router.get('/sliders', auth.isAuthenticated, role.isUserOrTeacher("admin", "teacher", "student"), controller.findAll)

  // You can add more routes and define which role is allowed to access

  module.exports = router;
```

authRole.js

```
  const isUserOrTeacher = (roleOne, roleTwo, roleThree) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      // codes
      for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        if (roles[i].name === roleOne || roles[i].name === roleTwo || roles[i].name === roleThree) {
          // codes
      }
      // codes
    }
  }
```